# How to delete duplicate records from data table?

Tags: c#

I have seen many examples on that but not able to fix the issue. I want to delete duplicate records from data table..

I have data like this

> A 2014-001268-01  Univ. of Tennessee -
>   Knoxville 1       20150101    455831126       Vogel   Patrick M   19861229    M   7705
>   Wilmington Dr
>
> A 2014-001268-01  Univ. of Tennessee -
>   Knoxville 1       20141201    455831126       Vogel   Patrick M   19861229    M   7705
>   Wilmington Dr

This is my code

```
List<DataRow> rows = new List<DataRow>();

foreach (DataRow row in fileDS.Tables[0].Rows)
    rows.Add(row);

DataTable table = DataTableExtensions.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>(rows);
IEnumerable<DataRow> uniqueContacts =
    table.AsEnumerable().Distinct(DataRowComparer.Default);
```

Comment: you need a new custom comparer

Comment: I would attack it further upstream and fix the part which allows dupes in the first place

Comment: I am uploading data from excel file.

Comment: Excel will hide duplicates and then you can upload the non-duplicate rows.

Comment: Excel has more columns which i need for other tables so i cannot hide them over there.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the job:

```
List<DataRow> rows = new List<DataRow>();

foreach (DataRow row in fileDS.Tables[0].Rows)
    if(!rows.Contains(row)) //Check if the List already have that row
       rows.Add(row);
```

if it doesn't work, try comparing strings from each row to the ones you already have inside the List